# 22.04.01 LTS - Steam game won't launch (Proton)

Tags: games, steam

I'm trying to launch a Steam game through Proton, but it just quits few seconds after launching. (no error, nothing shows up)

The game is Mudrunner, and while not native, it has "platinum" rating on ProtonDB.

Steam is installed off the website, and I've tried using the latest Proton version, older version 5.13-6 (which was recommended by multiple users), and also the latest GEProton version. Same results.

Here is the log: https://pastebin.com/LhebVqTn

HW:

```
cpu:                                                            
                       AMD A12-9720P RADEON R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G, 2355 MHz
                       AMD A12-9720P RADEON R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G, 2447 MHz
                       AMD A12-9720P RADEON R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G, 2497 MHz
                       AMD A12-9720P RADEON R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G, 1800 MHz
graphics card:
                       ATI Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
                       ATI Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics]
```

Any help is very appreciated. I'm new at Linux, so if more info is needed just let me know.

Comment: What launch arguments do you have configured for Mudrunner in Steam? The launch path looks weird, I don't know why it has PROT at the end `'/home/dominik/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/MudRunner/MudRunner.exePROT'`

Comment: Oh, that was totally my bad. I was testing out mutiple parameters and accidently left "PROT" after the %command% when I generated the log. That being said it doesn't work without it either.

Comment: So, uh... I tried the logical thing to do, which is to restart to see if that fixes anything, and it did. The game launches now, even had solid FPS of 40. However, I had this horrible screen tearing, so I did another restart to see if that helps. WRONG. FPS is now halved at 20, and the tearing remains. I honestly don't know what is happening anymore.

Comment: These restarts are magical. It's all working now. No tearing, fps is now 50. I'm scared to touch anything now. Also I forgot to notify, so I'll do that now ( @Baa ), in case you maybe know what happened, so that I may avoid this in the future.

Comment: Typically I find that in the first 5 - 10 minutes of Gameplay it will be rendering shaders and then it's much smoother after than, glad that's working good luck :)